# JQuery. Ajax request for each row in table

Tags: jquery, ajax

I tried do Ajax request for each row in table, but i can't achieve the desired result

Table:

```
<table>
        <tr class="data">
            <td class="editable">
                <a class="refresh btn btn-large" class="page">
                    Col one
                </a>
            </td>
            <td class="editable">
                <a href="#" data-pk="10" id="query" class="query">
                    Col two
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="data">
            <td class="editable">
                <a class="refresh btn btn-large" class="page">
                    Col one 1
                </a>
            </td>
            <td class="editable">
                <a href="#" data-pk="10" id="query" class="query">
                    Col two 1
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Ajax Request

```
$("#detect_rel").click(function(){
    $('.data').each(function(i, el) {
         var query   = $(el).children('.editable').children('.query').text();
        var page    = $(el).children('.editable').children('.page').text();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'wordstat/ajax?query='+query+'&page='+page,
            success: function(data){
                $(el).children('.editable').children('.relevantnost').html(data)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My problem: 
All ajax requests are sent at the one time, but i need do pause between requests.

P.s. About attribute "id" in tags: i should use it cuz of "Bootstrap X Editor"

Comment: Why do you need the pause?

Comment: Cuz between requests i should do some work, highlight current row and etc

Comment: @ВикторНовиков Why not just get all the data you need upfront and then stagger out the display of that data in the the success callback function as needed. For example, you could have a simple while looking for a specific condition to happen on element at index i-1 that would "block" the further execution of the success callback on the current item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that AJAX requests are asynchronous so if you do all of them within .each() there will be no pause.

What you need is to first take each of the `el` elements and place them in an array.
Then create a global variable that will be your counter to know how many requests have been sent.

You send your first request, and then send the second in the success function of the first, and so on.

You need to rewrite essentially, so that requests are sent as previous is finished.

**Example:**

```
function test()
{
    var arr = new Array();
    var counter = 0;

    $('.data').each(function(i, el) {
        arr.push(el);       
    });

    doRequest(counter);

    function doRequest(counter)
    {
        var query   = $(arr[counter]).children('.editable').children('.query').text();
        var page    = $(arr[counter]).children('.editable').children('.page').text();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.google.com?'+query+'&page='+page,
            success: function(data){
                alert("made request with query="+ query);   
                counter++;
                if(counter<arr.length)
                doRequest(counter);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**Edit:**

As I saw from the other answers you can just include `async: false,` which makes the requests asynchronous.

An approach similar to this is only useful for situations where `async:false` is not supported, or not preferable due to blocking the browser...

> Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support
>   synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may temporarily
>   lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active.

From: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings

Comment: I thought about it... Thankyou, i'll try ;)

Comment: This way is probably useful for situations where `async:false` is not supported, or not preferable: "Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active."

Comment: I use this script for "Cross-domain requests". Then i should't use `async:false`? Or i misunderstand (sorry if this is the case) you? P.s. `dataType:` not jsonp

Comment: async: false will not work for for cross-domain requests. Cross domain is if your javascript is running on one domain, and your trying to access another. E.g. IF your page is on http://a.com/test.html and your trying to access data from http://b.com/test.php . I think in your case everything is on the same server so `async:false` is better.

Comment: Oh, then i misunderstand it all. Cuz of: ajax do request to local script, which use cUrl for parse page from another server.. Then, i think, i can use `async: false`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you just need to create a closure around `el`:

```
(function(el) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'wordstat/ajax?query='+query+'&page='+page,
        success: function(data){
            $(el).children('.editable').children('.relevantnost').html(data)
        }
    });
})(el);
```

This will create a separate copy of `el` for each request, so each response will update its corresponding element.

(Note: if you really wanted to pause between each request, you could use `$.ajax`'s `async: false` option, but I can't see why you'd want to do that.)

Comment: Mb you right, and i really don't need it.
But i want check it, and i want to know how to do it.
Really big thx for your answer.

Comment: Yes, your answer is exellent. I put in the code `async: false`, and it something what i need. Sorry for bad English, if i do mistake somewhere (but i thing my mistakes anywhere :D )

Answer (score 1):

They AJAX requests are asynchronous, so as soon as one AJAX request if fired off, the next `each()` iteration is kicked off such that you likely have an number of parallel requests to the AJAX endpoint.  You can make the request asynchronous in the configuration if you want them to block. This would make them operate serially.

```
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: 'wordstat/ajax?query='+query+'&page='+page,
            success: function(data){
                $(el).children('.editable').children('.relevantnost').html(data)
            }
        });
```